# fixed item in mat-menu angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have this code snippet to show unread notification to user:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <div class="menu-item" mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of notifications">
        ...item content
    </div>
    <button class="show-all-btn" mat-menu-item (click)="navigateToNotification()">show all</button>
</mat-menu>
```

as you can see in the above code I generate menu item by *ngFor directive and as last menu item I add "show all" button that every time exist in my menu.
How can I show this button at the bottom of mat-menu in fixed position which can't move by scrolling items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with position sticky, min required styles are

```
.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-mat-menu-p1wpy7?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: I got this working without the position relative on .menu